# How to validate ios auto-renewable subscription receipt when latest_receipt_info is missing

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, receipt-validation

I have an app that has (only) auto-renewable subscriptions:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html

I have a backend where I validate the receipt. I use the `latest_receipt_info` value from the validation result JSON structure returned by apple to enable user's subscription. Sometimes this JSON key exists but sometimes it is missing. Here's an example response where this key is missing:

```
{
    "status":0,
    "environment":"Sandbox",
    "receipt":{
        "download_id":0,
        "adam_id":0,
        "request_date":"2018-03-22 10:28:02 Etc/GMT",
        "app_item_id":0,
        "original_purchase_date_pst":"2013-08-01 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
        "version_external_identifier":0,
        "receipt_creation_date":"2018-03-12 12:29:54 Etc/GMT",
        "in_app":[

        ],
        "original_purchase_date_ms":"1375340400000",
        "original_application_version":"1.0",
        "original_purchase_date":"2013-08-01 07:00:00 Etc/GMT",
        "request_date_ms":"1521714482146",
        "bundle_id":"my.App",
        "receipt_creation_date_pst":"2018-03-12 05:29:54 America/Los_Angeles",
        "application_version":"201824020001",
        "request_date_pst":"2018-03-22 03:28:02 America/Los_Angeles",
        "receipt_creation_date_ms":"1520857794000",
        "receipt_type":"ProductionSandbox"
    }
}
```

How should I handle this case? I need i.e. `transaction_id`, `product_id` fields in order to process the validated receipt.

Comment: What ever came of this?

Comment: I've started experiencing a large spike of cases this past month where the latest_receipt_info is missing.  Hasn't happened to me before which sent me looking  to see if anyone else had this issue.